# Invertibility of a square matrix with entries given by linearly independent functions

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, inverse

Consider a square matrix of the form
$$
M(x)=\left[
\begin{matrix}
f_{1,1}(x), f_{1,2}(x), \ldots, f_{1,k}(x)\\
f_{2,1}(x), f_{2,2}(x), \ldots, f_{2,k}(x)\\
\vdots \qquad  \vdots \qquad  \vdots \qquad  \vdots\\
f_{k,1}(x), f_{k,2}(x), \ldots, f_{k,k}(x))
\end{matrix}
\right]
$$
and assume:

**H.1** For each $(i,j) \in \{1,\ldots,k\}^2$, $f_{i,j}:\mathbb
R^d\mapsto \mathbb{R}$ and $f_{i,j}(x)=f_{j,i}(x)$, $\forall x \in \mathbb{R}^d$ (thus, for each $x$, $M(x)$ is symmetric);

**H.2** for each $i \in \{1,\ldots,k\}$, $(f_{i,1}, f_{i,2},\ldots, f_{i,k})$ are linearly independent functions.

Does this guarantee that $M(x)$ is invertible, for any $x \in \mathbb{R}^d$?

I would say no. My concern stems from the fact that linear independence only means that some functions are not a constant multiple of a linear combinations of the others, but (if I get it correctly) does no guarantee that for a given $x$, some $f_{i,j}(x)$ can not be expressed as a linear combination of the reals $ f_{i,1}(x),\dots,f_{i,j-1}(x),f_{i,j+1}(x), \ldots, f_{i,k}(x)$, with linear coefficients possibly depending on $x$. Am I missing anything stupid?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your intuition is correct. In fact, it can happen that $M(x)$ is singular for **all** $x$. Consider $k>1$ and
$$
M(x)=\pmatrix{
1&x&x^2&\cdots&x^{k-1}\\
x&x^2&\cdots&x^{k-1}&x^k\\
x^2&\cdots&x^{k-1}&x^k&x^{k+1}\\
\vdots&&&&\vdots\\
x^{k-1}&x^k&x^{k+1}&\cdots&x^{2k-2}}
$$
The powers of $x$ on each row are linearly independent over $\mathbb R$ because every non-trivial linear combination of them constitutes a nonzero polynomial function, but $M(x)$ is always singular because it is rank-one for every $x$.